# Relationship between the length of the whiskers and the tails of a population in boxplot

Tags: self-study, boxplot, heavy-tailed

Why in the boxplots long whiskers are associated with a heavy tailed distribution and short whiskers are associated with light tailed distributions populations?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like there's much to say: since the whiskers in all three of these plots are visual representations of the tails (specifically, the outer quarters of the distributions), what are you hoping the answers will tell you that isn't already extremely obvious?

Comment: @whuber I don't understood well the relationship between the length of the whiskers and the type of tail. If I have short whiskers it means that I have no much extreme values then it means that I have light tails?

Comment: That is precisely what the captions to the three graphics are telling you.